# How to setup authentication on jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I installed jenkins on a CentOS system. Now I am able to open the jenkins web page on localhost:8080. I want to add a login required for accessing this url. I enabled security on 'Configure Global Security' page then set 'Unix user/group database' under 'Security Realm'. In Authorization part, I set 'Logged-in users can do anything'. By doing this configuration, only logged in user can do build and modification on jobs. But there is a problem that users can still read all the jobs information without log in. How can I prevent anonymous users to access my jenkins web page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the "Matrix based security" helps you here. And then uncheck all the checkboxes from the Anonymous user.

Under the "Jenkins’ own user database" also uncheck the "Allow users to sign up" sign up option. This way you can prevent unwanted users.

Good luck!